# Отладка dll в МVS 2015

Tags: visual-c++, dll, отладка

Подскажите как производить отладку dll (с возможностью установки точек остановки, просмотром значений переменных и т.д.)

Это моя dll У меня 2 проекта, и открыто две студии в одной dll во второй программа которая ее использует. Ставлю в dll точку остановки но она не срабатывает... Что значит собрана вместе с программой?

Вроде [image: введите сюда описание изображения]все сделал...

но не работает..[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я добавил проект с dll к основному проекту на скринах видно. Но точка так и не срабатывает...

Comment: Во всплывайке на втором скриншоте подробно расписано, почему именно точка остановки не сработала и как это исправить. Вы пробовали сделать то, что там написано?

Comment: Офтоп. Конфигурация "x86" стандартная или сами делали?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы выполнять такую отладку должны быть выполнены условия:

1. Студия должны иметь доступ к отладочным символам (файлам `.pdb`) отлаживаемых модулей. У вас это условие выполняется, в окне вывода отладчика видны строки с текстом "символы загружены".
2. Отладочные символы должны соответствовать бинарям и исходниками. Тогда отладчик используя символы имеет возможность спозиционировать исходники в месте где стоит точка остановки. Если нет соответствия позиционирование выполнить не возможно. Соответствие символов бинарям выполняется автоматически так как символы генерируются при каждой компиляции бинаря. А вот с исходниками часто выходит что исходник изменен, а компиляция не выполнялась, то есть символы и бинарь остались старые.

Вот вторая ситуация у вас и наблюдается о чем вам и сообщает в подсказке студия.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать solution из двух проектов и один из них (с dll) добавить в зависимости другому (с exe).

Comment: забыл написать что это все в **одной** студии запущено должно быть :)

Comment: @Grundy, открыть один solution в двух студиях - это всегда не очень хорошая идея ;)

Comment: Ну собственно в вопросе так и есть :) _Это моя dll У меня 2 проекта, и **открыто две студии** в одной dll во второй программа которая ее использует._

Comment: @Grundy, в вопросе 2 solution'а, я предложил сделать один. Разве из этого не следует, что останется одна запущенная студия?

Comment: Неа :-) абсолютно не следует :)

Answer (score 0):

Две запущенные студии независимы друг от друга. Поэтому точка остановки установленная в одной студии не будет работать если запущена программа в другой студии.

Устанавливайте точки остановки **только** в той студии, в которой запускаете программу.

Comment: А как же attach to process?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, есть такой вариант, но при этом студия которая делает attach переходит в состояние `running`. Таким образом это аналогично  тому, что установить точку в студии запускающей